# Maven Error while running my selenium project in jenkins

Tags: selenium, maven-2, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

When running the top level maven target

```
test
```

I get the following error:

```
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins   /jobs/selenium/workspace"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:709)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:345)
at hudson.tasks.Maven.perform(Maven.java:263)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:717)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1502)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)
... 15 more
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
```

This seems to be an issue concerning the maven pathway, but I've setup the maven pathway on my host machine. M2_HOME, M2, and PATH are all correct. I know they are correct because I can run the maven commands from the command line. When I try to invoke maven commands in jenkins though I get the error.
So I went into `Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Configure System` and I clicked on Maven installations...
I checked off on

```
Install automatically
Version 2.2.1
```

I clicked save and tried to run my project again with the same error. When I do mvn -version I get 2.2.1 so that should be right.
From the Configure System page I have also tried

```
Name default
MAVEN_HOME /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-2.2.1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are those env variables defined in the startup script of the login shell for the user under which Jenkins is running? Have you restarted Jenkins ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to my question has two parts. First I needed to make sure that after creating the maven Installation setup on the Configure System page, that I specified that same configuration in the build itself. Second Jenkins does not seem to have sufficient privileges on the redhat box I'm running it on. Once I finally got it pointed to the right maven instance I got a lot of unable to create file/folder errors. These permission errors could be the real reason I had so much trouble with maven on this machine. I have not solved these permission errors and will create a new question for them.

Comment: Thanks OrwellHindenberg. Solution 1 worked for me. I added default maven installation in (Jenkins -> configuration), then went to failing Job's configuration and chose the default maven instance I had configured in (Jenkins -> configuration).